# Elmah bootstrapper clean logs

Tags: webforms, elmah

I would like to know where does elmah bootstrapper store logs and how can i make a function to delete them. Nothing on the documentation says how to store them or where they are stored....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH Bootstrapper doesn't store logs anywhere. It's a tool to help configure [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/) in a project. ELMAH, on the other hand, can store errors in a number of different destinations. There are loggers for in-memory, XML, SQL Server and much more. I've listed some of them in this [ELMAH Tutorial](https://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/).

The ELMAH documentation also have a list of the officially supported databases here: https://elmah.github.io/a/error-log-implementations/. For the full picture of ELMAH error loggers, you can check out this search on NuGet.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=elmah. To mention a few, there are third-party loggers available for RavenDB, PostgreSQL and MongoDB.